# ManualResetEvent.WaitOne() returning false without timeout?

Tags: c#, .net

What would cause `ManualResetEvent.WaitOne()` to return `false` besides a timeout?

We have a call to `WaitOne(3600000)` that is returning after about five minutes with `false`.

This behavior is seen on only one server out of about 300. We have not yet isolated anything different about that particular server. The call is in a Windows Service using .NET 4.0.

The code where we use the call looks basically like this:

```
 if (tracker.WaitOne(timeout)) {
     Log("Success");
     return;
 }
 Log("Timed out");
 throw new Exception(...);
```

We get the "Timed out" logs after about five minutes (not exactly).

Note the timeout isn't normally one hour. We extended the timeout for testing since it was timing out earlier than expected. Normally the timeout is configured to be ten minutes. In the vast majority of runs the tracker is `Set()` in less than a second, although rarely it can take a few minutes.

I also looked into if something could be disposing the wait handle but the only place it gets disposed is after it gets set. I also checked if disposing close after a set could cause the wait handle to incorrectly return false and in my tests on .NET 4 and .NET 4.5 the wait handle always returned true even when dispose was called immediately after the set.

Comment: Do you really need to have a one hour timeout while waiting for a MRE? That sounds like your design could be improved. What are you using it for?

Comment: And are you really sure the method returned false? Is it possible you're treating it as returning false when it throws an exception, for example?

Comment: @Luaan, thank you for your helpful questions. I added more details to explain.

Comment: "although rarely it can take a few minutes" so can it take *five* minutes?

Comment: @usr, yes, it can take five minutes. The early timeouts seem to be occurring randomly between 1 and 5 minutes for a period of several hours, then stop without explanation, and then start-up again without explanation.

Comment: @SamuelNeff so if you set the timeout to 5min and the wait takes 5min why are you surprised to see the call terminate and return false?

Comment: @usr, we're surprised because the timeout is set to an hour.

Comment: What's the scope of that `tracker`? Is it a field? Is it possible you're accessing it from multiple threads? It might cause some wacky behaviour (although it probably shouldn't). Try putting a stopwatch there to measure how long the wait took, and compare it with the usual `DateTime.Now - startTime`. Do all those servers have the same windows versions with the same updates?

Comment: @Luaan, tracker is a field in an object that's put in a producer/consumer queue (many producers, one consumer). When an item is removed from the queue, it's inside a try/finally that disposes the tracker if an error occurs, and logs the error. I did just now add logging to track exactly how long is elapsing to measure the wait time. The servers are across 300 clients, many different versions with many variations in updates.

Answer (score 2):

If it's happening on one server, and is reliably timing out sooner (5 minutes instead of 60) I might consider that machine having some kind of very strange clock problem.

The answer is honestly that it doesn't return false unless the timeout has elapsed (obviously, the timeout is not exact, but should not be that far off, and would more likely be 'late' than 'early') and so either your assertion is wrong somehow, or something's just really really wrong with that server at possibly even a hardware level.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If there was a clock problem then wouldn't that also affect the associated timestamps in the log files? We do know the log timestamps are accurate as certain log lines can be correlated across servers.

Comment: This doesn't sound right to me -- I mean -- the parameterless `WaitOne` method, which says it will block forever unless it's signaled, returns a `bool`. -- If it always blocks until signaled, and is only ever documented to return `true`... why does it need to return a `bool`? -- there must be some other exit condition.

Comment: The signature of WaitOne() in .NET just passes through to WaitOne() with parameters with an infinite timeout. It's just a convenience method with predefined parameters. Given that, would be bad to not return the same thing (a boolean) or else you're not properly passing return values up and swallowing them if for some reason it did return something you didn't expect.